# Detect the longest horizontal and vertical line in an image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I have a [pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zx2Qb0uprxXKM2qOjcljd5S-Cdftoavc/view?usp=sharing) from which I want to extract text. I use tesseract for OCR which does a good job. But my problem is that it does not recognize the 2 column format of the document and hence it merges the 2 columns together.

I want to split the document on the vertical (in the middle of the page) and horizontal (on top of the page) lines and then feed it to tesseract. So I do the following

Preprocessing steps:

```
# color to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 500, 1000, apertureSize=7)

# dialate
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=1)

# blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(edges, (7, 7), 0)
```

These steps produce:
[image: Pre-processed image]

Now, I do line detection:

```
minLineLength = 1000
maxLineGap = 500
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(processed_img, 1, np.pi, 2, minLineLength, maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 0), 1)
```

The final result (after stitching all the images back into a pdf) looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b2AgQ_GGnlNwgFI_pBtV9U5Irzi3M8jP/view?usp=sharing).

I have tried various combinations for `theta`, `minLineLength` and `maxLineGap` and this was the best result I could get. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is described below:

1) Detect the horizontal line. Below is one way to do this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def discard(image):
    image = np.uint8(image)
    _, im_label, stts, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=4)

    msk1 = np.isin(im_label, np.where(stts[:, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH] > 500)[0])
    msk2 = np.isin(im_label, np.where(stts[:, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT] > 500)[0])

    image[(msk1 | msk2)] = 0
    return image


img = cv2.imread("page_1.jpg", 0)
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.35, fy=0.35, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
height, width = img.shape[:2]

# Binarization
thresh = 255 - img
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(thresh, 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Discarding long connected components
without_lines = discard(thresh.copy())
just_lines = cv2.bitwise_xor(thresh, without_lines)
horizontal = just_lines.copy()

# separating horizontal line
h_kernel_large = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], np.uint8)
horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(horizontal, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, h_kernel_large, iterations=2)
cv2.imshow("horizontal_line", horizontal)
```

This is what we get in the horizontal matrix:
[image]

2) Use `findContours` and `boundingRect` to get the coordinates of that horizontal line. Then use that coordinate to crop the image horizontally.

```
upper_portion = img
lower_portion = img
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    upper_portion = img[0:y, 0:width]
    lower_portion = img[y+h:height, 0:width]

cv2.imshow("upper_portion", upper_portion)
cv2.imshow("lower_portion", lower_portion)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Below are images after cropping.

upper_portion:
[image]

lower_portion:
[image]

3) Detect the vertical line and crop lower_portion image using the same procedure described in step 1.

In step one, I basically used "Connected Component Analysis" followed by an "Opening operation". Read them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) and [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html)

Comment: That works like a charm! Could you add a little more text explaining what you are doing in step 1? I am an OpenCV newbie, so I didn't follow it completely. Also, how would you change this for the vertical lines? Just the kernel matrix?

Comment: Exactly. You just need to change the kernel matrix.

Comment: Thanks! Accepting the answer now. Will comment if I get stuck again :)